How to use payer and minter fields in mintV2 from metaplex
I am playing around with metaplex and umi. Trying to create a collection with candy machine to mint from that candy machine. I have created candy machine and inserted my assets in that candy machine. Now, I want to mint from that candy machine. What I am trying to do is that, mimic the real world scenario where a person pays for the mint. For that, I have tried below approach:
const mintFromCandyMachine = async (candyMachine: KeypairSigner, collectinMint: KeypairSigner) => {
    const nftMint = generateSigner(umi); // address of newly minted nft
    const minter = await walletSecretToArray();
    minter && await transactionBuilder()
        .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 800_000 }))
        .add(
            mintV2(umi, {
                candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
                nftMint: nftMint,
                collectionMint: collectinMint.publicKey,
                collectionUpdateAuthority: myKeypair.publicKey,
                minter: minter,
                payer: minter

            })
        )
    }

const walletSecretToArray = async () => {
    const secretUint8Array = process.env.DEV_WALLET_SECRET && bs58.decode('2W6VSdXgXVquZKyvTRYhW7TEKLc2qbd4gXwV8u8kiAdphWfhMkqNWKcbggxgc2xwXCiXHTF3dSvexW1VwH12ZNW5');
    return secretUint8Array && Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretUint8Array)
    // const secretKeyArray = secretUintArray && Array.from(secretUintArray);
    // const userWallet = secretKeyArray && Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secretKeyArray));
    // const myKeypair = userWallet && umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(userWallet?.secretKey);
    // return myKeypair;
}


However, I get below error for minter and payer fields in mintV2 function
Type 'Keypair' is missing the following properties from type 'Signer': signMessage, signTransaction, signAllTransactionsts(2739)
mintV2.d.ts(28, 5): The expected type comes from property 'minter' which is declared here on type 'MintV2InstructionAccounts & MintV2InstructionDataArgs<DefaultGuardSetMintArgs>'

How do I create Signer for minter and payer fields?
Here is how I created the umi instance
const solanaConnection = new Connection(endpoint);
const umi = createUmi(solanaConnection).use(mplTokenMetadata()).use(mplCandyMachine());
const userWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secret));
const myKeypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(userWallet.secretKey);
const myKeypairSigner: KeypairSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, myKeypair);
const irys = getIrysUploaderInstance(umi, myKeypairSigner);
umi.use(signerIdentity(myKeypairSigner));


Found the solution. I need to create the keyPairSigner for the wallet that wants to mint. So, needed to use createSignerFromKeypair function. So, the function walletSecretToArray is now changed to
const createMinterWalletSigner = async () => {
    const secretUint8Array = process.env.DEV_WALLET_SECRET && bs58.decode(process.env.DEV_WALLET_SECRET);
    const secretKeyArray = secretUint8Array && Array.from(secretUint8Array);
    const userWallet = secretKeyArray && Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secretKeyArray));
    const myKeypair = userWallet && umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(userWallet?.secretKey);
    const minterKeyPairSigner = myKeypair && createSignerFromKeypair(umi, myKeypair);
    return minterKeyPairSigner;
}

Not the best written function but, it is just for experimentation purpose for now
